# MIDI file displays with treble staff only

Tags: midi, sibelius

I have a MIDI file, installed Sibelius intending to have Sibelius read the MIDI file and display it as sheet music. It does. But treble staff only; the lower notes are all on ledger lines. It's a giant pain to try to read. Basically I find it impossible. The single staff, the treble is labelled "Kontakt," which is the name of a MIDI converter program.

1. Open Sibelius
2. new project
3. choose piano staff, treble and bass, other options look okay as-is.
4. file, open, > choose the MIDI file
5. sheet music opens, single staff as described above
6. one more thing, the MIDI playback when I hit "play" in Sibelius sounds like absolute crap. Wooden, clunky, no dynamics, ... Nothing like the performance it is supposed to be reproducing.

Comment: This is about very basic use of the application. Try the Sibelius support forums?

Comment: If it was saved as only one track the MIDI file may not contain the necessary info regarding which hand does what. But unless it's a long or complex piece of music it should take only a minute to select all the errant notes and move them to an adjacent staff of your choosing. I wonder if you are familiar with the Reference Guide. There is a section on importing MIDI, and another on playback devices, both of which might be prove useful. Let the wise words of piiperi Reinstate Monica be as a torch to light your way.

Comment: Try this: open a grand staff, copy the notes to the treble staff set a split point and reorganize the setting. http://www.sibelius.com/download/plugins/index.html?plugin=98

Answer (score -1):

This plugin should work: (s. my comment above)

Split Point One Staff

*For use with Sibelius 4 and Sibelius 4.1
Split Point One Staff processes two staves. It moves notes on or above the split point to one staff, and notes below the split point to the other staff. Usually the high notes go to the top staff, but you can choose to have them go to the bottom staff. It will only work if one of the staves is empty, not when both staves have notes.*

For Sibelius 5, use the shipping Change Split Point plugin.

http://www.sibelius.com/download/plugins/index.html?plugin=98

Comment: And what’s the question?